# Finding the determinant of a matrix given the adjoint

Tags: matrices, adjoint-operators

[image]

My attempt:

Knowing that $$A(AdjA) = IdetA$$
I took the determinant on both sides: $$det(A)det(AdjA) = det(det(A))$$
So, $$det(A)det(AdjA) = (det(A))^3$$
$$det(AdjA) = (det(A))^2$$
$$det(A) = (AdjA)^{0.5}$$
The adjoint was calculated to be 4

Thus, $$det(A) = 4^{0.5}=2$$

Why is the answer -2?

Comment: $x^2 = 4$ does not imply $x = 2$, but $x = 2$ or $x = -2$.

Comment: Ah, I see. However, why is the answer exclusively -2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation does not allow you to choose between  $-2$ and $2$. But then you are not using the information you have about  $A $.

Assuming that as you say  $$\tag {1}A (\text {Adj}\,A)=I\,\det A, $$ the $3,3$ entry in (1) is the third row of $A $ times the third column of the adjoint; and this should equal  $\det A $. So
$$
\det A=1\times (-1)+ 2\times (-1)+ 1\times1=-2.
$$

Comment: So, basically you can find the detA by simply multiplying a row from matrix A with a column from AdjA at the same position(e.g. row 2 with column 2)?

Comment: Yes. It the equation you wrote: the product of $A $ and its adjoint has $\det A $ in each of the diagonal entries.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to is to using [cofactor formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29#Cofactor_expansion_of_the_determinant). We have 
$$\det(A)=a_{31}C_{31}+a_{32}C_{32}+a_{33}C_{33}
=C_{31}+2C_{32}+C_{33}.$$
From the adjoint of $A$, we know that 
$$C_{31}=-1, C_{32}=-1, C_{33}=1.$$
Therefore, we have 
$$\det(A)=C_{31}+2C_{32}+C_{33}=-1-2+1=-2.$$